# Product import problem. Cannot be used with directory

Tags: import

I have a problem with import product. When i try import using this option, also import not working when i use "Advanced Pricing" but when i try use for example "Customer Addresses" import working correctly.

[image]

My exception.log call me error like

`[2021-05-14 06:39:32] main.CRITICAL: Path "/var/www/html/store/var/importexport//DhrGxu1C7TTHZiuhYqftgqXk3seWjyZr.csv" cannot be used with directory "/var/www/html/store/pub/media/" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\ValidatorException(code: 0): Path \"/var/www/html/store/var/importexport//DhrGxu1C7TTHZiuhYqftgqXk3seWjyZr.csv\" cannot be used with directory \"/var/www/html/store/pub/media/\" at /var/www/html/store/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/PathValidator.php:63)"} []`

I set up permission 777 to var and pub folder. I have created directory like:

`var/export`
`var/import`
`var/import_hisotry`
`var/importexport`

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ownership over those folders is properly set to the webserver user as well as setting the proper permissions over media folder too.

Comment: Ownership is properly set. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: hmm not really at this point

Comment: Do you think it should be database problem?

Comment: this doesn't look like a db problem.